# Normalizing Flows Invertibility

Tags: probability, neural-networks, mathematical-statistics, generative-models, normalizing-flow

I am currently reading up on RealNVP, which has the following transformations according [Lilian Weng](https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2018-10-13-flow-models/):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{y}_{1:d} &= \mathbf{x}_{1:d} \\ 
\mathbf{y}_{d+1:D} &= \mathbf{x}_{d+1:D} \odot \exp({s(\mathbf{x}_{1:d})}) + t(\mathbf{x}_{1:d})
\end{aligned}
$$

I am wondering how the inverse has the scale and shift networks simply reparameterized by the outputs $\mathbf{y}_i$'s instead. Wouldn't the learned weights only provide mappings from $\mathbf{x} \rightarrow \mathbf{y}$?

Here is the math to show invertibility:
$$
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{y}_{1:d} &= \mathbf{x}_{1:d} \\ 
\mathbf{y}_{d+1:D} &= \mathbf{x}_{d+1:D} \odot \exp({s(\mathbf{x}_{1:d})}) + t(\mathbf{x}_{1:d})
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{x}_{1:d} &= \mathbf{y}_{1:d} \\ 
\mathbf{x}_{d+1:D} &= (\mathbf{y}_{d+1:D} - t(\mathbf{y}_{1:d})) \odot \exp(-s(\mathbf{y}_{1:d}))
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is important to recognize again that the so called coupling layers are splitted into two. One part directly passes to next layer without any modifications (i.e. $\pmb x_{1:d}$). That's why you can just write $\pmb x_{1:d}$ instead of $\pmb y_{1:d}$ in the inverse formulation:

\begin{cases}
\mathbf{x}_{1:d} &= \mathbf{y}_{1:d} \\ 
\mathbf{x}_{d+1:D} &= (\mathbf{y}_{d+1:D} - t(\mathbf{y}_{1:d})) \odot \exp(-s(\mathbf{y}_{1:d}))
\end{cases}
Which is equivalent to
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{x}_{1:d} &= \mathbf{y}_{1:d} \\ 
\mathbf{x}_{d+1:D} \odot \exp(s(\mathbf{y}_{1:d})) +  t(\mathbf{y}_{1:d}) &= \mathbf{y}_{d+1:D}
\end{cases}
As you can see, we acquired back the same result as the forward formulation of $\mathbf{y}_{1:d}$.